# ffmpeg constantly running out of memory

Tags: command-line, memory, ffmpeg, webserver

I use ffmpeg on a wordpress site with a bunch of different commands and logic, which work about half the time. One day everything will run fine while other days I get "cannot allocate memory" errors. Sometimes rebooting my server helps. It doesn't matter what ffmpeg commands and options I use cause it happens randomly, but it seems to happen more often when using `-filter complex`.

My ffmpeg build -

```
ffmpeg version N-90767-g768c077-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/cpffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslint
  libavutil      56. 15.100 / 56. 15.100
  libavcodec     58. 19.100 / 58. 19.100
  libavformat    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 18.100 /  7. 18.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
```

My server specs -

```
50GB of storage 
4GB of RAM
```

Using command line `ulimit -a`

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1030613
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1030613
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

wordpress wp-config

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '99999M' );
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '99999M' );
```

How can I find if there's a memory leak and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What does phpinfo(); say your max_memory is set to?

I bet that configuration directive is being ignored/ not picked up / overwritten by another configuration. You may not actually be able to increase memory limits in this fashion, depending on your Apache configurations.